# Difference between User::class and new User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-service-container

I am using Laravel 8. I want to know the difference between `new User()` and `User::class` because I am having trouble while using `new User()`.

Here is the scenario,

I have `UserServices` class in which I am injecting `UserRepository` class

```
class UserServices
{
    private $userRepository;
    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function findUserByEmail($email){
        return $this->userRepository->findUserByEmail($email);
    }

}
```

Now in service provider when I bind the UserServices class using following way I am getting following error

`ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function`

```
$this->app->bind(UserServices::class, function($app){
    return new UserServices();
});
```

But when I use `UserServices::class` then it works fine

```
$this->app->bind(UserServices::class);
```

Why?

I know that `UserServices` class constructor is expecting parameter then why working with `UserServices::class`

**//Working**
`$this->app->bind(UserServices::class);`

**//Not Working**

```
$this->app->bind(UserServices::class, function($app){
    return new UserServices();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you're providing an explicit constructor which attempts to return an instance of the class, but does it incorrectly.

In the second case, you're leaving it up to the service container to determine dependencies and [inject them automatically](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#automatic-injection), which does it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an interface then you need to bind the interface with the related class in the service provider. Otherwise you don't need any binding